# Can't get sf::Text to work

Tags: c++, text, sfml

recently I've encountered a problem. I can't get sf::Text to work. No idea why, font seems to be loading.
Here's the code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
// Create the main window
sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

sf::Font font;
sf::Text text;
if(!font.loadFromFile("/usr/share/fonts/TTF/arial.ttf"))
   std::cout<<"Error";
text.setFont(font);
text.setCharacterSize(30);
text.setColor(sf::Color::Blue);
// Start the game loop
while (app.isOpen())
{
    // Clear screen
    app.clear();

    // Draw the sprite
    app.draw(text);

    // Update the window
    app.display();
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't know anything about SFML but do you actually set a text for `text` somewhere? I see only font and color.

Comment: try `text.setString("Hello World");` Somewhere before your game loop

Comment: Ahh, I'm so dumb. Sorry for wasting your time xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    sf::Text infoText;
    infoText.setPosition(0.0f, SCREEN_Y-23.0f);
    infoText.setCharacterSize(20);
    infoText.setString("press i for info");
    infoText.setFont(*resourceManager()->getFont(ResourceManager::FontResources::sansation_ttf));
```

works for me.  Are you getting an error, or is it just not showing up?

EDIT: What's text did you give it?  It may be initialized it "".  The default position is likely (0,0) so that shouldn't be a problem, even though you don't set it explicitly.